# Getting a garbage value while printing matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I learned C programming language three years back and now when i am revisiting it after the experience of java and c# i'm facing some issues with pointers. So i tried to write a simple matrix addition program but i don't know why i'm getting some strange values while printing the matrices.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* sumOfMat(int* m1,int* m2)
{
    printf("Matrix A: \n");
    printMat(m1);
    printf("Matrix B: \n");
    printMat(m2);
    int mat3[3][3];
    int row=0,col=0,k=0,sum=0;
    for(;row<3;row++)
    {
        col=0;
        for (;col<3 ;col++ )
        {
            sum=(*m1+*m2);
            m1++;
            m2++;
            mat3[row][col]=sum;
        }
    }

    printf("Result: \n");
//    printMat(mat3);  //this statement is giving me a correct output.
    return mat3;
}

void printMat(const int m[3][3])
{
    int row,col;
    for (row=0;row<3 ;row++ )
    {
        for (col=0;col<3 ;col++ )
        {
            printf("%d\t",m[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}


int main(void) {
int mat1[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int mat2[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
//add
printf("Sum of the metrices : \n");
int* x=sumOfMat(&mat1,&mat2);
printMat(x);   // this call is providing me some garbage values at some locations.
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Success  time: 0 memory: 2292 signal:0
Sum of the metrices : 
Matrix A: 
1   2   3   
4   5   6   
7   8   9   
Matrix B: 
1   2   3   
4   5   6   
7   8   9   
Result: 
2   134514448   134514448   
8   10  12  
14  16  -1216458764
```

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/fork/dXvsjq)**

Question: Why i'm getting this error and how to correct it.

Comment: For one, mat3 is declared on the stack, but it is returned and used (after it is popped from stack).  There are other issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the line

```
int mat3[3][3];
```

allocates your 2d array on the *stack*

You're returning a pointer to this array.

```
return mat3;
```

Unfortunately when the function call ends the stack is unwound and the memory for the array is no longer there, so you have a pointer to garbage.

One solution is to allocate the array in your `main` function and pass it into `sumOfMat` as a parameter.

Comment: This was my first attempt when i was explaining the result of function call from the function itself but why i'm getting incorrect for only three places? was it by chance only or something else ?

Comment: @Arpit if I understand your comment rightly, I think you're asking why are some of the numbers correct and some incorrect? This is because the memory for your 2d array won't get overwritten with other stuff immediately, so some correct values will persist for a while. (From a language the behaviour is *undefined*, so the result of trying to access that memory is unpredictable.)

Answer (score 2):

Never return a pointer to an *automatic* variable:

```
int *f(void)
{
    int i;
    ....
    return &i;
}
```

The variable `i` doesn't exist once `f` returns, so the pointer to it will be invalid.
In your case `mat3` is an automatic variable and `sumOfMat()` returns a pointer to `mat3` which does't exist once `sumOfMat()` returns.
One of the solution for your problem is, define `mat3` as global variable.

Further I pointed out one major problem with your code:

*Return type of`sumOfMat(int* m1,int* m2)` is pointer to integer (`int *`) while you are returning `mat3` which is of type `int(*)[3]`.*
I got lots of warnings while compiling your code. I corrected most of them.
Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printMat(int *m);
int* sumOfMat(int* m1,int* m2);
int mat3[3][3];

int* sumOfMat(int* m1,int* m2)
{
    printf("Matrix A: \n");
    printMat(m1);
    printf("Matrix B: \n");
    printMat(m2);
    //int mat3[3][3];
    int row=0,col=0,sum=0;
    for(;row<3;row++)
    {
        col=0;
        for (;col<3 ;col++ )
        {
            sum=(*m1+*m2);
            m1++;
            m2++;
            mat3[row][col]=sum;
        }
    }

   printf("Result: \n");
   //    printMat(mat3);  //this statement is giving me a correct output.
   return mat3[0];
}

void printMat(int *m)
{
    int row;
    for (row=1;row<=9 ;row++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",*m++);
            if(row%3 == 0)
                printf("\n");
        }
   /* {
        for (col=0;col<3 ;col++ )
        {
            printf("%d\t",m[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/

}


int main(void) {
int mat1[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int mat2[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
//add
printf("Sum of the metrices : \n");
int* x=sumOfMat(&mat1[0][0],&mat2[0][0]);
printMat(x);   // this call is providing me some garbage values at some locations.
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are returning `mat3` which is a local variable defined as

```
int mat3[3][3];
```

To correct this either do a dynamic allocation of `mat3` using `malloc` OR pass it as a `out variable` in the function `sumOfMat` as third variable.